# how can I test text that is put in to input elements?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a web page that pulls some data from my database when someone types an integer into a text box. The data ends up in some text input controls. Straightforward. The selenium that fires the ajax is:

```
<tr>
    <td>fireEvent</td>
    <td>ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wiz1_Control1_TextBox1</td>
    <td>blur</td>
</tr>
```

After the blur event, there are 6 inputs on the page that now have text in them. I want to **wait for the text to be present** in the inputs and assert that they are present. What's an effective way to do this?

I've tried:

- `waitForExpression` with a jquery call
  (`$('...').val() != ''` but doubtful
  that this works because of the
  jquery, even though jquery is loaded
  on the page); also tried xpath, but that didn't work either
- `waitForText` ( locator, pattern ), which seems like the most obvious one, but it really won't work, i suspect since the fields are inputs

Do I need a different approach here because the elements that I'm querying are `input` controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution (as provided by the users on the Selenium google group) is to use **waitForValue** instead of waitForText. On the one hand, this could've been a lot easier to figure out. On the other, I could've known more about the DOM object I was testing.

```
<tr>
  <td>waitForValue</td>
  <td>ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TheTextBox</td>
  <td>regexp:.+</td>
</tr>
```

[>>> Google groups link](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_frm/thread/941916741194027a/62327db46eb9eb6a?tvc=1#62327db46eb9eb6a)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I would do; This will wait for an value in all TextBoxes up to 60 seconds.. When there is a value in all of them, you check them etc and break out of the loop. Otherwise it will fail after 60 seconds.

```
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
  if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
  try { 
    if (selenium.getValue("TextBox1") != "" && selenium.getValue("TextBox2") !="" )) 
      { Your Logic here..
         break;
       } 
   } catch (Exception e) {}
  Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me the table formatted html version of this that will work with the IDE? I suspect the issue that I'm having is with the IDE.